# Select ordered rows up to certain id

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
INSERT INTO "public"."catalog_element" 
("id", "catalogue_id", "element_id", "weight") VALUES
(1,100,1,0),
(2,100,2,1),
(3,100,3,2),
(4,10,1,0),
(5,10,5,0),
(6,10,6,1),
(7,100,7,1);
```

Let say, we have a Postgres table of `catalog *- to -* element` matching rows that are weighted, like such

| id | catalogue_id | element_id | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 100 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 10 | 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 10 | 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 100 | 7 | 1 |

I try to write a query that will return records bounded to certain `catalog_id`, ordered by weight, in a range between first to one that have certain `element_id`.

Like this where `catalog_id = 100` ordered `DESC` by weight and **every rows up until `element_id = 7` meet** , which end up with this result:

| id | catalogue_id | element_id | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 100 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 100 | 7 | 1 |

Comment: What is the criterium to include the second row, the one with `element_id - 2`. You don't specify if you want to include those rows with the same `weight` as the one with `element_id=7`.

Comment: Criterium to include — that this rows are preceding in ordered view for lookup one `element_id=7`.

Comment: if the row in question precedes or succeeds the cut of row is not well defined since it has the same weight. My answer assumes all with same weight should be included, but can easily be changed to the inverse if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to get the weight wanted and the select the column that are bigger than that weight

```
SELECT
"id", "catalogue_id", "element_id", "weight"
FROM catalog_element
WHERE "catalogue_id" = 100 AND weight >= (SELECT weight FROM catalog_element WHERE "element_id" = 7)
```

| id | catalogue_id | element_id | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 100 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 100 | 7 | 1 |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sM69P0Vm)

Comment: Hm, interesting, thanks, but I guess It wouldn't guarantee order in some cases. I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok, it would result with false-positive results if `id` is not the primary key.

Comment: The order, as a result of an SQL query, can only be guaranteed by adding an `ORDER BY ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you consider my solution less clunky.
It does avoid the self join, which *should* result in better performance for large tables.

```sql
select * from (
  select
    coalesce(lag(max_flag,1) over (order by weight desc, flag),0) lmf,
    wmf.*
  from (
    select 
      max(flag) over( order by weight desc, flag) max_flag,
      wf.* 
    from (
      select
        case
          when element_id = 7 then 1
          else 0
        end flag,
        ce.* 
      from catalog_element ce
      where catalogue_id = 100
    ) wf
  ) wmf
) wlmf
where lmf =0;
```

yields

| lmf | max_flag | flag | id | catalogue_id | element_id | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 100 | 3 | 2 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 100 | 7 | 1 |

With the following setup

```sql
create table catalog_element (
 id integer, 
 catalogue_id integer, 
 element_id integer, 
 weight integer
);


INSERT INTO catalog_element 
(id, catalogue_id, element_id, weight) VALUES
(1,100,1,0),
(2,100,2,1),
(3,100,3,2),
(4,10,1,0),
(5,10,5,0),
(6,10,6,1),
(7,100,7,1);
```

While statements like this seem intimidating they are actually not that hard to understand.

1. You used [analytic or windowing functions yourself, so I assume basic knowledge of their working](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/).
2. since you can't directly nest such functions I use nested selects, where each nesting level adds a function. Therefore such statements should be read from the inside out.
3. The inner most one `wf` for *with_flag* adds a `flag` column using

   ```sql
    case
        when element_id = 7 then 1
        else 0
    end flag
   ```

   marking the cut off row. This happens in its own subselect, since
   we need the flag twice in the next step.
4. In `wmf` for *with_max_flag* we use `max(flag) over( order by weight desc, flag)` to create the `max_flag` column that has a `0` for all rows before the cut off row. Not that we order by `flag` as well to have `0` also for those rows with the same weight as the cut off row.
5. We can now almost filter by that row, but we want to include the row cut off row, so we us `lag` to basically shift the `max_flag` by one row, and use `coalesce` to turn `null` values into `0`.
   This happens in `wlmf` for *with_lagged_max_flag*.
6. We finally filter out only the rows that we want.

The resulting SQL statement looks clumsy, but it does access the data only once and orders by the same criteria all the time.
My experience with similar and actually way bigger statements is that they perform extremely well.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Nn8jwJ7jENNFqaGQgWs1G/0)

Comment: Oh my, this is a voodoo!

Comment: I added some explanation for what is going on. I promise, no magic, no voodoo, no animals harmed.

Comment: @nbk gave a query that result with the same outcome, but more compact. Sadly, my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/75521369/342879 is one that work correctly even in corner case, that I wasn't able to describe clear, when id isn't primary key, and default order defined by column combination.

Comment: @nbk solution is fine as far as I can tell, and certainly is more compact, which is of  value on its own. Mine will probably perform better on big data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Using LATERAL to compute max relevant weight. Take all the rows with  greater weight and only rows till element_id = 7 having exactly that weight. May return more than one row for element_id = 7. Define an extra criteria to select a single element_id = 7 row.

```
select "id", "catalogue_id", "element_id", "weight"
from catalog_element e
cross join lateral (
    SELECT max(e2.weight) maxw
    FROM catalog_element e2 
    WHERE e2."element_id" = 7 and e2.catalogue_id = e.catalogue_id 
) t 
where "catalogue_id" = 100 
   and weight >= t.maxw   
   and (weight > t.maxw or element_id <= 7)
order by weight desc, element_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the way to do what I desire, but it's to clunky

```sql
WITH ordered_catalogue_elements AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY weight DESC, id ASC)
    FROM catalogue
    WHERE 
        catalogue_id = 100
)
SELECT *
FROM ordered_catalogue_elements
WHERE row_number <= (
    SELECT row_number
    FROM ordered_catalogue_elements
    WHERE element_id = 7
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To select ordered rows up to a certain ID on the data in the given insert statement, you can use the following SQL query:

```
    SELECT * FROM catalog_element
    WHERE id <= <max_id>
    ORDER BY catalogue_id ASC, weight ASC, element_id ASC;
```

Replace <max_id> with the maximum ID value that you want to include in the results. This query will select all rows from the catalog_element table where the ID value is less than or equal to the specified maximum ID, and order the results first by catalogue_id in ascending order, then by weight in ascending order, and finally by element_id in ascending order.

For example, if you want to select all rows with an ID value less than or equal to 5, the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_element
WHERE id <= 5
ORDER BY catalogue_id ASC, weight ASC, element_id ASC;
```

This would return the following rows:

```
id  | catalogue_id | element_id | weight
----+-------------+------------+-------
1   | 100         | 1          | 0
2   | 100         | 2          | 1
3   | 100         | 3          | 2
4   | 10          | 1          | 0
5   | 10          | 5          | 0
```

Comment: **id** can't be order predicate in my case, weight is.
So this query wouldn't do what I need.

Comment: let me recheck it, and hopefully, you will get clarity.